# Running eslint command every time you save

Tags: npm, build, eslint, package.json

I have my package.json script set up like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src webpack.config.js || exit 0"
  },
```

How can I have this lint command run every time I save a file so I don't have to run `npm run lint` every single time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[eslint-watch](https://github.com/rizowski/eslint-watch) looks like it would do this:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint-watch": "esw --watch src webpack.config.js"
}
```

Comment: Perfect, do you know how I can concurrently run this with my webpack dev server